# Is it possible to extract particular information from Google Cloud Logging entries in the Logs Explorer?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-logging

In the Logs Explorer of Cloud Loggging on the GCP I'm getting such textPayload here from  NGINX for example. Now I would like to extract or at least highlight specific parts, e.g. error code or response time.

```
23.23.23.23 - - [24/May/2023:13:41:49 +0000] "POST /api/my-endpoint HTTP/1.1" 502 186 "-" "Google-ActionsOnGoogle/1.0" 3309 1.905 [app-somewild-service-80] [] 10.2.124.159:8081 186 1.904 502 218057012395790
```

Is this possible directly in the Logs Explorer?

Sure, I can export the logs and do it somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

You can extract metric data from the content of log entries using Log-based metrics in cloud Logging. To search the contents of the **Query results**, click **Find in results** in the **Query results** pane, and then enter your search term. This filter lets you find information in your log entries without building a new query.

For example, if you want to extract error and timestamp of app engine metrics write an expression into the Logs Explorer query-editor field and click **Run query**. Logs that match your query are listed under **Query results.**

You can refer to the [queries](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/query-library#using-queries) grouped by Google cloud services.

For example, below is the expression for App engine logs for one day.

```
resource.type="gae_app" AND
severity>=ERROR AND
timestamp>="2023-05-24T00:00:00Z" AND timestamp<="2023-05-25T00:00:00Z"
```

Type this expression in query-editor and run the query. You will find the desired results in the Query results tab.

For more information, you can refer to this [document](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/building-queries#queries-with-time-restriction).

Comment: +1 For "Find in results" haven't noticed it, yet. But unfortunately, it does not support regex so, searching for timings is not so easy.